# What is the difference of meaning between the phase angle of S11 and the phase angle of Γ (Gamma)?

Tags: rf, impedance, load, reflection, reflection-coefficient

I realized recently that the Touchstone "DB" S-parameter format (.s1p, etc) uses the phase angle of \$\angle \Gamma\$ instead of \$\angle S_{11}\$ and wondered why it didn't use the phase angle of the complex S11 measurement.  .

Given the complex variables:

- \$\Gamma = \frac{Z_{load}-Z_0}{Z_{load}+Z_0}\$
- \$S_{11} = 20*{clog}_{10}(\Gamma) \$

and phase angle function  \$\angle c = {carg}(z) = {atan}(\frac{b}{a})\$ where \$z = a+bi\$,

It seems strange to me that the "real" part would be in DB but the phase part would be from \$\Gamma\$ which is outside of the clog() function; perhaps the meaning of the phase angle in \$\Gamma\$ is lost after going through clog()?

Questions:

- Is there a meaningful difference between \$\angle S_{11}\$ and \$\angle \Gamma\$?

  - Is \$\angle S_{11}\$ the phase angle of the reflected wave?
  - If so, then what does \$\angle \Gamma\$ mean: what is useful about the phase angle of the reflection coefficient \$\Gamma\$
  - How is that be more useful than \$\angle S_{11}\$ in an RF data format?
- When would you use one over the other?

Please don't answer "because that is convention" or "because of a Touchstone file format design decision" because I'm trying to understand the difference in between \$\angle S_{11}\$ and \$\angle \Gamma\$ in a meaningful way.  It may come down to a design decision, but when would the phase angle of one vs the other be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems strange to me that the "real" part would be in DB but the phase part would be from Γ which is outside of the clog() function; perhaps the meaning of the phase angle in Γ is lost after going through clog()?

This is a misinterpretation of the formula. If you were to actually keep only the real part, your conversion would simply be wrong. Γ = 0 + j1 is an S11 of 0 dB @ 90 degrees, not an S11 of -infinity dB as you suggest.

The value wasn't changed, its magnitude was just represented on a logarithmic scale. Converting "this amplifier has 14 dB voltage gain with a phase shift of 4°" to "this amplifier's H(ω) is 4.9997 + 0.3496i" is the same idea.

> Is there a meaningful difference between ∠S11 and ∠Γ?

No. It's the same numerical value. S11 is commonly *represented in* log-scale, and gamma is often *represented in* linear scale measurement. For example, I may choose to give this value of a circuit as 0.7071 + j0.7071 (i.e. 1.000∠45°), or as "0 dB, angle of 45°"

> Is ∠S11 the phase angle of the reflected wave?

Yes. If the returning *voltage* wave is in-phase with the incident voltage wave (interfering constructively at the point of measurement), then S11 has an angle of 0. If the returning *current* wave is in-phase with the incident current wave (interfering constructively at the point of measurement) then S11 has an angle of 180 degrees.

> If so, then what does ∠Γ
> mean: what is useful about the phase angle of the reflection coefficient Γ

Gamma *is* S11. See previous answer.

> How is that be more useful than ∠S11 in an RF data format?

It's the same angle.

> When would you use one over the other?

Same remarks about numerical precision [that I've given in the past](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/589854/9612). For the same reason, you may choose between phase-magnitude or real-imaginary representation of gamma/S11 as you see fit for your numerical precision needs.

Comment: So in the touchstone DB format, is the real column a magnitude as `|S11|` or just the real component as `real(S11)`?

Comment: @KJ7LNW I do not know the touchstone DB format in particular, but reporting the log-scale of only the real part of S11 is fairly nonsensical. If you were to report just the real part, you immediately create needless ambiguities and complexity -- what numerical gamma would "-infinity dB, 90 degrees phase" mean? (0+j0.1)? (0+j1)? (0+j99999999)? Applying the same guidance as before - if you have a doubt that you can't resolve, hook up your VNA to the DUT and see what it reports in the different formats.

Comment: Where `Γ` is complex, `clog10` is complex log10, and `log10` is real log10: it turns out that `real(20*clog10( Γ )) == 20*log10(cabs(Γ))` holds true with tiny a floating point error: `creal(cs11)=-6.4614700088017338 20*log10(cabs(cgamma))=-6.4614700088017347 diff=-8.8817841970012523e-16`.  These must be algebraically equivalent.